# Condicionais em xml

Tags: string, xml, condição

Estou trabalhando num `arquivo.xml` e preciso declarar uma propriedade caso a string que recebo como parâmetro **não** seja vazia.

```
<condition>
    <property name="SHAZAM" value="Esse é o conteúdo ${env.SHAZAM}">
</condition>
```

Como posso implementar isso?

Answer (score 1):

Usando xml encontrei algumas respostas aqui:
[Condicionais em XML (StackOverflow Inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061470/if-then-else-using-xml)

Ou usando xslt desta forma:

```
<xsl:if test="1 == 2">
     <property name="SHAZAM" value="Esse é o conteúdo ${env.SHAZAM}">
</xsl:if>
```